# Use whereIn and with in the Eloquent Model of Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship as `Restaurant` has Many `Jobs`

[image: Job Model]

[image: Restaurant Model]

I have properly set the methods in `Restaurant` and `Jobs` model.

I am creating a query where the `job.status` is in `active` or `upcoming` and with that I need `restaurant` data too.

Below is my code:

```
Job::whereIn("status", ['upcoming', 'active'])->with(['restaurant'])->get();
```

with this I am getting `restaurant` as `null`

As I am novice in Laravel, I tried the other way around also.

```
Job::with(['restaurant'])->whereIn("status", ['upcoming', 'active'])->get();
```

But it gave the same result.

However, if I use `where` it works properly.
Below is the code which is working and providing `restaurant` data.

```
Job::where("end_date_time", '>=', $currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->with(['restaurant'])->get();
```

I saw the documentation and I found that `whereIn` is Collections method, so is it something that it will not work if we have `with`?

I searched on google any example of `whereIn` and `with`, but I didn't found any.

May I am doing some conceptual mistake in understanding `whereIn` and `with`

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do your relationships look like? What does the data in your database look like?

Comment: Hi @miken32, I just discovered that the data restaurant data is not coming with ```where``` where column is ```status```, if I have other column like ```end_date_time``` restaurant data is getting populated.

Comment: I have updated the post and added model images too.

Comment: Pictures are not helpful. Copy/paste information into your question.

Comment: in your question you get different results with two different where queries? If restaurant is null it is because restaurant_id in your job table is null, can you check that?